# Bootstrap modal to show "Registration Success" text on the same modal after filling-in the sign-up form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I tried to make sign up form using Bootstrap Modal and, after successful sign-up, I need to show a success message in the same modal. How can I do it?

I tried follow this tutorial - [link](https://www.codexworld.com/bootstrap-modal-popup-form-submit-jquery-ajax-php/) but it doesn't post the data to a database.

I deleted some input code in the form because it was too long.

Insert Form

```
<div class="modal fade" id="daftarModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Daftar</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <form method="post" action="#" id="daftarForm">

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="forEmail" class="col-sm-2">Email</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="forEmail" name="email" >
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="forNama" class="col-sm-2">Nama</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="forNama" name="nama" >
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Jenis Kelamin</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="radioBtn ">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="j_kel" id="forLaki-Laki" value="Laki-Laki">
                                <label for="forLaki-Laki" class="form-check-label">
                                    Laki-Laki
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="j_kel" id="forPerempuan" value="Perempuan">
                                <label for="forPerempuan" class="form-check-label">
                                    Perempuan
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Paket</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="checkBtn ">
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="paket[]" id="forA" value="A">
                                <label for="forA" class="form-check-label">
                                    Paket A
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="paket[]" id="forB" value="B">
                                <label for="forB" class="form-check-label">
                                    Paket B
                                </label>
                            </div><div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="paket[]" id="forC" value="C">
                                <label for="forC" class="form-check-label">
                                    Paket C
                                </label>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="paket[]" id="forD" value="D">
                                <label for="forD" class="form-check-label">
                                    Paket Daaa
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Daftar">
                    </div>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#daftarForm').on('submit', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:"daftarForm.php",
            method:"POST",
            data:$('#daftarForm').serialize(),
            success:function(data)
            {
                $('#daftarForm')[0].reset();
                $('#daftarModal').modal('hide');

            }
        })
    });
});
```

PHP

```php
if(!empty($_POST)) {
        $output = '';
        $email = $_POST["email"];
        $nama = $_POST["nama"];
        $j_kel = $_POST["j_kel"];
        $alamat = $_POST["alamat"];
        $telepon = $_POST["telepon"];
        $asalSekolah = $_POST["asalSekolah"];
        $paketArray = implode(',',$_POST['paket']);

        $sql = $koneksi->query("INSERT INTO `peserta` (`id`, `email`, `nama`, `j_kel`, `alamat`, `no_hp`, `asal_sekolah`, `paket`) VALUES (NULL, '$email', '$nama', '$j_kel', '$alamat', '$telepon', '$asalSekolah', '$paketArray');");

        if($sql) {
            $output .= '<label class="text-success">Pendaftaran Berhasil</label>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<label class="text-success">Pendaftaran Gagal</label>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: what problem u get in this???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are hiding the modal on `success` using this `$('#daftarModal').modal('hide');`

Create a banner in the modal like this an initially hide it. On success call `show` method

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // rest of the code
  success: function(data) {
    $('#daftarForm')[0].reset();
    // show banner here
    $('#banner').show();
   }
  });
```

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="daftarModal">
  <div class='hiddenBanner' id="banner"> Success</div>
  // rest of the code
</div>
```